# How to list RPM packages that depend on a specific library?

Tags: fedora, rpm, libraries

I would like to determine which RPM packages on my Fedora 25 system depend on the libraries `libLLVM-3.8.so` and `libclang-3.8.so`. How do I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dnf repoquery` to find this. For example:

```
dnf repoquery --whatrequires libLLVM-3.8.so
```

however, on an x86_64 system, this might not do quite what you want; to specify the x86_64 version of a library (which probably *is* what you want), tack on `()(64bit)`, like this:

```
dnf repoquery --whatrequires 'libLLVM-3.8.so()(64bit)'
```

(With `'` now necessary to keep the parentheses from confusing bash.)

By default, this lists both available and installed packages; to restrict to the ones that are currently installed, add the `--installed` flag, like so:

```
dnf repoquery --whatrequires 'libLLVM-3.8.so()(64bit)'  --installed
```

which on my system, returns:

```
llvm-libs-0:3.8.0-1.fc25.x86_64
mesa-dri-drivers-0:13.0.2-2.fc25.x86_64
mesa-libxatracker-0:13.0.2-2.fc25.x86_64
```

If you want just package names, add `--queryformat '%{name}\n'`. (Use `dnf repoquery --querytags` to get other formatting options.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ locate libLLVM-3.8.so
/usr/lib/libLLVM-3.8.so
/usr/lib64/libLLVM-3.8.so
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libLLVM-3.8.so
llvm-libs-3.8.0-1.fc25.x86_64
$ sudo rpm -e --test llvm-libs-3.8.0-1.fc25.x86_64
error: Failed dependencies:
        libLLVM-3.8.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) clang-libs-3.8.0-2.fc25.x86_64
        libLLVM-3.8.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mesa-dri-drivers-13.0.2-2.fc25.x86_64
        libLLVM-3.8.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mesa-libOpenCL-13.0.2-2.fc25.x86_64
        libLLVM-3.8.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mesa-libxatracker-13.0.2-2.fc25.x86_64
```

Similary for the other file. Or any file.

Comment: Doesn't really work for me just gives `error: Failed dependencies:
        llvm-libs(x86-64) = 3.8.0-1.fc25 is needed by (installed) llvm-3.8.0-1.fc25.x86_64`. Must admit that wasn't really enlightening to me, as I already knew llvm-libs was there partly to satisfy the dependency of llvm.